# Google app engine file upload by user in codeigniter using php

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am trying to upload the file which size is greater than 100MB in Google app engine through php. I successfully downloaded the sdk and integrated in my app. But I'm getting an error like:

```
Fatal error: Class
'google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CreateUploadURLRequest' not found
in
project_path/google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php
on line 145
```

Comment: Have you checked that the file exists at that location?

Comment: Yes, the files are in same place but still i am getting error i dont know why